# regular expression: ".*\\s([0-9]+)\\snomination.*$"

Tags: r, regex

Could someone explain why `"Won 1 Oscar."` can be picked out according to the regular expression given as below

```
awards <- c("Won 1 Oscar.",
"Won 1 Oscar. Another 9 wins & 24 nominations.",
"1 win and 2 nominations.",
"2 wins & 3 nominations.",
"Nominated for 2 Golden Globes. 1 more win & 2 nominations.",
"4 wins & 1 nomination.")

sub(".*\\s([0-9]+)\\snomination.*$", "\\1", awards)
```

I can only get that the pattern is `"abcd (any number 0 -9 ) nominationabcd"`. Once the pattern is matched, the number will replace the whole string. The matched `"Won 1 Oscar"` comes from the second element. What I am confused is that there is no `nomination.*` following `"Won 1 "` and why there seems to be no replacement.

Comment: It does not get replaced as it does not match your expression, that's all, see this demo: https://ideone.com/R03jGK

Comment: From paragraph 4 of the Value section of `?gsub`: *Elements of character vectors x which are not substituted will be returned unchanged*.

Comment: @Jan @Imo so it means `gsub` will return a vector of length 5 too. If there is no match, the original element will be returned, right?

Comment: @DXC: A length of six in your example - with one string unchanged, that is.

Comment: @Jan sorry for my typo. Yes, the first string is not changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gsub` function takes the regex (or a plain string if you use `fixed=TRUE`) and tries to find a match in the input character vector. If the match is found, this match is replaced with the replacement string/pattern. If the match is not found, thecurrent character (string) is returned unchanged.

Since you want to get the only nominations value from each element of the character vector, you need to *extract* them, rather than replace the matches.

You may rely on the *stringr* `str_extract`:

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract(awards, "[0-9]+(?=\\s*nomination)")
[1] NA   "24" "2"  "3"  "2"  "1"
```

The `[0-9]+(?=\\s*nomination)` pattern finds 1 or more digits but only those that are followed with 0+ whitespaces and `nomination`  char sequence (these whitespaces and the "nomination" word are excluded from the matches as this is a pattern inside a positive lookahead (`(?=...)`) construct that is non-consuming, i.e. not putting the matched text into the match value).